# VMWare tools grayed out - Kubuntu 17.04 / VMWare Fusion 8

Tags: kubuntu

I have a fresh guest install of Kubuntu 17.04 and it will not allow me to install VMware tools.  This is in VMWare Fusion 8.  The option for 'Install VMWare Tools' is grayed out. I have tried a few different things, but have yet to get it enabled and install.  HELP!

Comment: There could be fifty million reasons it's greyed out, but you don't need to use the VMware Tools installer, you can install the open-source versions of the tools from the repositories without issue.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the open source ones in the repositories?  They work extremely well and provide pretty much all the same tools.

Within the guest OS, run this:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop
```

This installs an open-source version of the VMware-compatible tools, and provides most of the features you'd be looking for from the standard VMware Tools.

Once installed, reboot the VM, though, to get all the kVMware-tools-compatible parts enabled (and so that VMware recognizes it's got a compatible set of tools installed).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my Mac with High Sierra and Fusion 11 installed.  What I had to do to get this to work:

1. Shutdown my running VM (it happened to be Ubuntu 14.04)
2. Go to VM -> Settings and Click Add Device in the top right corner
3. Once in the Add Device dialog, add a new CD/DVD-ROM drive.  Make sure that the drive is set to auto-detect.
4. Restart the VM and you should now be able to run 'Install VMWare Tools'
5. Last, for my Ubuntu VM, I followed these directions to get installed: [VMWare Tools Install Instructions](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1022525)